# Symbolize Flow Direction on Line Feature in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, symbology, arcgis-online

I seems that ESRI has a serious limitation as it seems you can't symbolize the direction on water lines in ArcGIS Online.  With server you can.

From the reading on Esri forums this is a known problem - caused by complex symbology needed on the line in the publishing MXD.

Just wondering if anybody has found a good work around they would share.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea you could try - AGOL supports rotation values on points. Could you create points from the line and have a way to determine the bearing direction and have that set as the rotation value on the points which could be an arrow and showing the flow direction.

Comment: Hey Russ,  Yeah - thought about this - wondering if that would be harder to maintain than building tile cache's? Half a dozen or 6 at this point. What is frustrating is that a Map Service created on ArcServer can render the flow directions in a browser, but the same MXD shared to AGOL cannot handle the Geometry.  Unfortunately I need a solution that does not use ArcServer for this project.

Comment: Yup you could create a hosted tile service with png 8 so it respects transparency and you could have just the cached network of pipes with flow direction and just recook a tpk and upload it and generate a new hosted tiled service.